# Reuse other command's "interactive" form

Tags: commands, interactive

Example, I want to define a `package-open-homepage` command, which reuses <kbd>C-h P</kbd> (`describe-package`)'s "interactive" form. I don't want to copy-and-paste because it is too long. The following

```el
(eval
 `(defun package-open-homepage (pkg)
    "Open homepage of pkg, or do nothing if none."
    ,(interactive-form 'describe-package)
    (when-let ((desc (cadr (assq pkg package-alist)))
               (extras (package-desc-extras desc))
               (homepage (cdr (assoc :url extras))))
      (browse-url homepage))))
```

works, but I never use `eval` before, is this use case the reason that why `eval` is needed? and is there any other way without using `eval`?

By the way, I already know `(put 'package-open-homepage 'interactive-form (interactive-form 'describe-package))` works.

Comment: If you know about the `interactive-form` symbol property, then you have an answer already. You should at least *post that as an answer* to your own question.

Comment: `advice-eval-interactive-spec` from `nadvice` can be used to evaluate interactive forms. It uses eval internally, too. You can use it as a more general solution to evaluate interactive specs.

Comment: Note that, as of 2022-ish and Emacs 29, commit bffc4cb39d made it so that `commandp` will now raise an error if a command has an `interactive-form` property.  There was a question about this in [bug #55925](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=55925), but as of this writing that bug has never been addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own solution (setting the symbol property) is a perfectly fine way to go IMHO.

If you don't care about interactive forms with string literal values (the following won't work with those), your own interactive form could eval the other command's interactive form at run-time:

```el
(defun foo (&rest args)
  (interactive
   (eval (cadr (interactive-form 'COMMAND))))
  (message "%S" args))
```