# Using advice to run function before tag symbol lookup

Tags: advice, ctags, tags, xref

I use `xref-find-definition` to look up the definition of a symbol name. When I call `xref-find-definition`, I want to Emacs to automatically find and load an appropriately named etags file. For this purpose, I have a function, `open-tags-file`:

```
(defadvice xref-find-definitions (before before-xref-find-definitions activate)
  (open-tags-file))

(defun open-tags-file ()
  (interactive)
  (if (booleanp tags-file-name)
    (when (file-exists-p "my_tag_file")
      (visit-tags-table "my_tag_file"))))
  )
)
```

This works fine when I run `xref-find-definitions` with the cursor already over an existing symbol name. It also works if I do not have the cursor over a symbol name -- Emacs will prompt me to enter a symbol name, such as "CreateFood". Either way, The tags file is automatically loaded, and then the symbol is looked up.

However, when Emacs prompts me to enter a symbol name, I want to be able to type a partial symbol name, such as "Cre", and then press Tab and have "CreateFood" be auto-completed. If I do that, Emacs will prompt me to load the tag file, and it will expect it to have the name TAGS. This means that my `defadvice xref-find-definitions` is not being run before Emacs prompts me to enter the symbol name, it is only run after that symbol name is entered.

Is there a way to run `open-tags-file` before the symbol name is entered, so that I can auto-complete "Cre" into "CreateFood" when entering the symbol name to find the definition of?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use [the new advice system `nadvice`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) instead of the old one.
2. `xref-find-definitions` prompts the user already in its `interactive-form`. So you need to run `open-tags-file` in the `interactive-form` of your advice for the case that `xref-find-definitions` is called interactively.
3. I use the interactive specification of `xref-find-definitions` of emacs 25.3.1 in `my-xref-find-definitions-interactive-spec`. It may be that you need to adapt that to your emacs version. See the comment in the code. A variant would be to query the interactive form of `xref-find-definitions` with the help of function `interactive-form`. But that would complicate the code.
4. The code is untested. Please test it for yourself and comment whether it is working for you or not.
5. You usage of `tags-file-name` looks a bit strange. I think your test should be `(unless (stringp tags-file-name) ...)`. That would be more descriptive.

   ```el
   (require 'xref)

   (defun open-tags-file ()
     "Use \"my_tag_file\" as tag file for xref."
     (interactive)
     (unless (stringp tags-file-name)
         (when (file-exists-p "my_tag_file")
           (visit-tags-table "my_tag_file"))))

   (defun my-xref-find-definitions-interactive-spec ()
     "Interactive form for `open-tags-file'."
     (open-tags-file)
     ;; The following is the interactive specification of `xref-find-definitions' in emacs 25.3.1.
     ;; It may be that you need to adapt it to your emacs version.
     (list (xref--read-identifier "Find definitions of: ")))

   (defun my-xref-find-definitions-before-ad (&rest _args)
     "Advice for `xref-find-definitions' that handles the \"my_tag_file\"."
     (interactive (my-xref-find-definitions-interactive-spec))
     (open-tags-file))

   (advice-add 'xref-find-definitions :before #'my-xref-find-definitions-before-ad)
   ```

Comment: How would I, as you put it, "query the interactive form of xref-find-definitions with the help of function interactive-form"? I would prefer doing this to creating my own  interactive prompt, as I would like this to be compatible with different versions of Emacs. (Also, I would like to replicate the same tab completion functionality for other functions, such as xref-find-references and find-tag, when xref isn't available. That's more reason to call the default versions of interactive functions rather than having per-function customizations everywhere.)

Comment: @std_answ For re-using `interactive-form` of some command see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28518/reuse-other-commands-interactive-form. Especially interesting for you is [phils' answer there](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28520/2370).